# How do I change the email I use to log in to Stack Exchange without creating an Open ID?

Tags: feature-request, support, user-accounts, account-recovery

As you can tell by the title I need to change the email I use to login to my Stack Exchange account. However, after browsing many questions on this topic, most answers involve creating an OpenID account.

After many searches I have concluded that I have no reason to create an OpenID account since none of the sites I use utilize OpenID, nor is there a good reason to create an OpenID account. I'm currently in the process of migrating all my accounts on my current email to another email address and the Stack Exchange account is the only one remaining to be changed.

Any help would be appreciated, but I really don't want an OpenID account. Also I would also like to request this feature be added to Stack Exchange to enable users to change the email address associated with their account.

Comment: SE uses openid internally - I distinctly recall deleting and adding it back in the past, though I use my google account and my open Openid providers as backups

Comment: You are already using OpenID, even if you're not aware of that. There is no way to change the email associated with OpenID provider, the only option is to create a new, different, OpenID and use it.